# Como podría mostrar el resultado de aplicar una función para filtrar? Por ejemplo "Viendo 8 de 12", "Viendo 4 de 12" etc

Tags: javascript

Estoy armando una pagina de e-commerce y los productos pueden filtrarse por categoría o por calificación.
En la parte superior del catalogo hay un párrafo que muestra que cantidad de productos se visualizan una vez aplicado el filtro, por ejemplo "Viendo 4 de 20 productos", Viendo 6 de 20 productos".

Tengo la función en JS para filtrar y necesito saber:
*Como puedo mostrar el numero resultante en ese párrafo (por ejemplo "4" o "6")

```
like so
```

Comment: Saludos. Te falto agregar el código (html y javascript) así como si usas plugins o framework para ello; así se te puede sugerir que hacer para que tu código devuelva el resultado deseado.

Comment: Gracias! Ya lo agrego